# How to solve "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

I am developing this app on the frontend and here is the problem:

When I click on a thumbnail, it should open the big image with a carousel. However, this message appears and the style is not applied.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

**"[Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Uok2etT07nimvrD0JBY/ZlYS3xAfAdOKAkUmemu2L5w='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."**